# Proof in which sup A is related to inf B

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A \ne \emptyset$ also $A \subset [1,3].$ Define $B$ to be the set of positive real numbers $x$ such that $\sqrt{x}-1$ is an upper bound of $A.$ Prove that $\inf B = (1 + \sup A)^2.$

Here are my thoughts so far:

1) $\sup A \le \inf B$

2) Since $B$ is an upper bound of $A$, it must be the case that $\sup A \le \sqrt{x}-1$ $\Rightarrow$ $(1 + \sup A )^2 \le x$

Are these statements correct so far?  Also, Why can we say that $x = \inf B$?

Comment: Am I allowed to say " Let x be greatest lower bound of B "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x\in B\implies \sqrt{x}-1\ge \sup A\implies (1+\sup A)^2\le \inf B$. On the other hand, by definition of set $B$, $(1+\sup A)^2\in B\implies (1+\sup A)^2\ge \inf B$.

Comment: Thank you, but how do I get equality instead of $\le$ or $\ge$?

Comment: $a\le b,\ a\ge b\implies a=b$

Comment: Genius!!! Thank you for your help!!!